# How can I check to see if a range of timestamps are in a specific interval?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to return a true or false if a range of timestamps are in a specific interval?

Here's the code I'm using, these timestamps are in 5 minute intervals. So I would expect True to be printed.

I'm pretty sure that range can't be applied to a dataframe, so it would need to be converted to a series. Getting stuck though.

```
d = {'time': ['1/1/2021 00:00:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:05:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:10:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:15:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
start_date_inside = df['time'].min()
end_date_inside = df['time'].max()
s = pd.Series(df)

for x in s():
    if x(range(start_date_inside, end_date_inside, 5)):
        print('True')
    else:
        print("false")
```

This generates this error: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: This is not how you convert a frame to a series and is causing the error `s = pd.Series(df)` and your times are string objects and not datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'time': ['1/1/2021 00:00:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:05:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:10:00',
              '1/1/2021 00:15:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# convert to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
# calculate the difference and check to see if the difference is five minutes
df['time'].diff() == pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

or you can check if all values are exactly five minute intervals from the previous row

```
all((df['time'].diff() == pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)).iloc[1:]) # -> True
```